# Python - Import all files in a directory tree

Tags: python, django, reflection, introspection

I want to import all python files in a directory tree, i.e. if we have the following directory structure:

```
tests/
tests/foo.py
tests/subtests/bar.py
```

(Imagine that the tree is of arbitrary depth).

I would like to do `import_all('tests')` and load `foo.py` and `bar.py`. Importing with the usual modules names (`tests.foo` and `tests.subtests.bar`) would be nice, but is not required.

My actual use case is that I have a whole bunch of code containing django forms; I want to identify which forms use a particular field class. My plan for the above code is to load all of my code, and then examine all loaded classes to find form classes.

What's a nice, simple way to go about this in python 2.7?

Comment: Any reason not to use os.walk() http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

Comment: @GaryWalker Not particularly, but os.walk is not a complete solution in itself.

Comment: [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#__import__) or better [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) for Python 3.1+

Comment: I guess I just assumed you would load modules dynamically. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/769534/dynamic-loading-of-python-modules for an example. Not sure that this is necessarily a good idea -- depends up what you want to accomplish

Comment: @poke Unless I'm very much mistaken, `__import__` does not work with filenames, but module names.

Comment: @GaryWalker My purpose is explained in the question. As to that answer, it relies on `__import__`, which as far as I can tell does not use filenames, but module names.

Comment: @Marcin Modules are named by their file names.

Comment: @poke try doing `__import__('tests/subtests/bar.py')` and get back to me.

Comment: Well, *of course* that’s not how it works. But `__import__('tests.subtests.bar')` will work if `tests` and `tests.subtests` are packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rough and ready version using `os.walk`:

```
import os
prefix = 'tests/unit'
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(prefix):
    trimmedmods = [f[:f.find('.py')] for f in filenames if not f.startswith('__') and f.find('.py') > 0]
    for m in trimmedmods: 
        mod = dirpath.replace('/','.')+'.'+m
        print mod
        __import__(mod)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

my_dir = '/whatever/directory/'
files = [os.path.join(dirpath, f) for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(my_dir) for f in files if f.endswith('.py')]
modules = [__import__(os.path.splitext(f)[0],globals(),locals(),[],-1) for f in files]
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this won't import anything in subdirectories.

Comment: no for sure, the os.walk could solve the tree issue like in your example, but what I wanted to show here is the usage of import which allow to play with fully qualified name ...